# Attempting all possible pairs on a grid and keep a record for improvements to sides matches

Tags: java

Please go easy if I fail to explain anything.

Basically I wish to find out how I can keep a record of swapping all points in a tetravex grid. [ref: http://gamegix.com/tetravex/game].

I've created the grid and added the tiles from a random solution. I can currently swap ONE pair of USER-generated tiles but cannot do this as an automatic process.

How would one generally automate the process of swapping items automatically? AND keep a record of the "good" swaps

The swap method accepts the following parameters:

```
ems.swap(i1, j1, i2, j2);
```

Where `i1,j1` is the first tile which you want to swap and `i2,j2` is the second  tile you want to swap.

Once this is done, the tiles are assessed,

```
 public static int AssessSwapTiles(EdgeMatchSolution ems, EdgeMatch em)
{
    int a = em.getRows();
    int b = em.getColumns();
    int swaptotal = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
        {
            int numSides = ems.sidesMatched(i,j);
            System.out.print(numSides + " ");
            swaptotal += numSides;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println(swaptotal);
    return swaptotal;
}
```

This method is called once before the swap and again AFTER the swap.

Apologies for a long explanation, it was only for those who would stumble upon on this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to store this would be to use a [`Map<Swap, Int>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) where `Swap` is a class that holds `i1`, `j1`, `i2`, `j2` (and has `equals` and `hashCode` methods defined). The "good" swaps are the `Swap`s with the largest value.

Alternatively, you could use a 4-dimensional array to store the swap values, indexed by the swap made, i.e. `swapValues[i1][j1][i2][j2]` would be the value of swapping `i1`,`j1` with `i2`, `j2`.

I'm not sure what you plan on doing beyond storing the swaps, so it's hard to say what would be a better way of storing "good" swaps without more information.

Comment: Can you suggest an alternate method of doing this as I am not familiar with Map and only wish to use the so called basics and build my way up. Sorry to seem rude.

Comment: Also I am planning to use the best swaps but want to keep a record for future references

Comment: @JohnFillipe I updated the OP with your request. However, I'd recommend reading up on the Java collections api (which I linked for `Map`) as they are generally an integral part of any Java program.